# Does 6LowPAN stack helps in requirement of gateway?

Tags: networking, 6lowpan

After 6LowPAN stack. Every node can have the different internet IPv6 address.
So,

1. Is 6LOWPAN stack is present in GATEWAY or sensor mote as well?
2. In a case of sensor mote, is a GATEWAY required? Can't 6LOWPAN enable sensor to directly connect to IPv6 Router?

Correct me if I am missing some fact or data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any case, a 6LoWPAN enabled Sensor Network needs a Gateway to interact with an end user who might be using a standard 802.11 WLAN or a 802.3 Ethernet based network.

The Gateway needs to translate the 6LoWPAN enabled IPv6 addresses into addresses that standard networks can understand and communicate. For instance, if a node with 6LoWPAN enabled on it with Header Compression has Address `::1` there needs to be some defined way to know how to access this sensor node over a connected network. For that you need a gateway which does translation for you.

Have a look into [6lbr by CETIC](https://github.com/cetic/6lbr/wiki) for some more implementation specific example.

Read this Awesome [IPv6-WSN-Book](https://github.com/alignan/IPv6-WSN-book) for better understanding of 6LoWPAN

Comment: Just follow up question.
Before 6LowPAN you can address the WSN nodes. What advantage 6LoWPAN gives? I will read your resources if answer lies in them but else please just see...

Comment: WSN nodes work on 802.15.4 have max. MTU of __127 Bytes__ IPv6 Addresses take a lot of space. 6LoWPAN compresses these IPv6 Addresses so that they can fit into the MTU and makes addressing simple within a network

Comment: Ok. I will check how they used to get address before 6LowPAN then.

Comment: the First Chapter of the Book will give you all the idea.